# Retrieve a list of supported countries from Stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've read over Stripe's API and couldn't find a way to find if a country is supported by Stripe.

e.g: I have an user who is going to receive a payment and he is from a country, I need to check if he can use Stripe to receive this payment based on his country.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such info as I know in api, but there are not so many countries they support at he moment to accept payments. https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-countries-does-stripe-support

So you can add them into a global variable to your app and update it whenever a new country will be in the list. A settings page in admin panel may be, so you can easily update the list.

Comment: That's the list of countries the Stripe _account owner_ can be from. In theory, they should accept _payments_ from much more than that list.

Answer (score 5):

Stripe's Country Specs API should do what you need:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_country_specs

Their documentation includes sample code and sample responses for multiple languages.

Comment: It includes "preview" countries but not private beta countries. I guess it is enough for most uses.